# django: request.POST key is empty if the choicefield value is not set

Tags: python, django, web-applications

I am currently beginning web development using django. In my application, I want a form with a varied number of questions and their choices to be presented.

In *models.py*, a table is create to store the questions

```
class QuizItems(models.Model):
    question = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    choices = SeparatedValuesField(token="$")
    answer = models.IntegerField()
```

In *form.py*, I overload the __init__ method in Form class so as to pass qchoose, a list of QuizItems instances to create the form fields.

```
def choiceItem(question):
    return [(unicode(idx), q) for idx, q in enumerate(question.choices)] 

class QuizForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, qchoose, *args, **kwargs):
        super(QuizForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for q in qchoose:
            self.fields[str(q.id)] = forms.ChoiceField(required=True,
              label=q.question, widget=forms.RadioSelect(),choices=choiceItem(q))
```

Then in *view.py*

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    idlst = request.POST.keys()
else:
    # qchoose is a list of quizitems
    form = QuizForm(qchoose)
```

In *quiz.html*

```
{% for field in form %}
<li><b> {{ field.label }} </b></li>                                                                                                                      
<ul> {{ field }} </ul>
{% endfor %}
```

I want to get idlst, the list of question id, that I can get the correct answers from. It works fine when all the choicefields are filled. The problem is if there is any choicefield value is empty, I won't get its key. I think since the request.POST is a dictionary, it is supposed to return all the keys even if its value is empty.
Could anyone help me what is wrong with my code or anything missing? Thank you!

Comment: Initially I am unsure as to whether or not you are checking the values of the request.POST   QueryDict django is handing back to you.  You are not showing us the code lines where the actual error is occurring.

Answer (score 1):

You're supposed to use the form on POST as well, then call `is_valid()` and access the form's `cleaned_data` dict.

Comment: I used `form = QuizForm(qchoose, request.POST)` to get the form back but the `form.is_valid()` does not work correctly as it still returns True when there is empty value.
I think it is because there is no key in request.POST associated with the empty value then no error raised.
I don't know why keys are not returned.